# Detect type of an uninitialized object

Tags: java, class, types, detect

Suppose I have an uninitialized object such as:

```
MyClass A=null;
```

How do I detect that the type of A is MyClass? `A instanceof MyClass.class` is not working. It's returning false. And `A.getClass()` throws a `NullPointerException`. Is there a way to find the type of such uninitialized objects?

Edit:

The actual scenario is that `MyClassA`, `MyClassB` and `MyClassC` are subclasses of `MyClass`. So I'd be using the following code:

```
MyClassB B=null;
MyClass MC=B;
```

Now, at runtime, I need to determine if MC is an "instance of" `MyClassA` or `MyClassB` or `MyClassC`. Is there a way to do that?

Edit 2:

By detecting the type at runtime, I'd be able to do something like:

```
MyClass C=null;
...
//detect the type of C and instantiate the base class with an instance of that type
MyClass MC=new MyClassC();
```

Basically, I'll be passed the objects of all the subclasses, and I'll have to determine the type of each object and instantiate the base class with that type and return it.

Edit 3:

Finally found a partial way to do it! Relying on polymorphism to do that:

```
MyClassC C=null;
detect(C);
....
detect(MyClassA a){}
detect(MyClassB b){}
detect(MyClassC c){ //MyClassC detected! }
```

However, if I'm passed the `MyClass` object,this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You know the static (compile time) type of that variable - it's `MyClass`. You don't need `instanceof` or `A.getClass`.

`instanceof` or `A.getClass` are useful when you need to know the run-time time of the instance referred by the variable. This has no meaning when the variable contains `null`.

EDIT :

If `MC` is null, it's not an instance of anything. It makes no difference if you write

```
MyClassB B=null;
MyClass MC=B;
```

or

```
MyClassC C=null;
MyClass MC=C;
```

or

```
MyClass MC=null;
```

In all those cases `MC` would contain the same `null` value, and it won't have any type other than its compile-time type, which is `MyClass`.

EDIT 2:

You can instantiate the correct class when you assign to MC :

```
MyClassC C = null;
MyClass MC = C==null?new MyClassC():C;
```

At the time you assign `C` to `MC`, you know the type of `C` and you can create an instance of `MyClassC` if it's null.

Comment: Have edited the question to explain the problem a little more. Bottom line is that the detection needs to happen at runtime on an uninitialized object variable.

Comment: So is there no way of finding the compile time type of the object at runtime?

Comment: @Ashley How would it help you to know that the `null` value of `MC` was assigned from a variable of type MyClassC? You can't cast it to MyClassC. You can't invoke any methods of MyClassC. You should only use `MC isntanceof something` if MC is not null.

Comment: Have edited the question to describe what my requirement is. Thanks!

Comment: When I recieve C, my code wouldn't be knowing that its of type `MyClassC`. And hence the requirement for the runtime type detection.

Comment: @Ashley how would you receive C?

Comment: Thanks @Eran! You gave me a spark! Now half of my problem is solved. But half still remains. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The instanceof operator allows you determine the type of an object. What we have here is a reference and not an object, if we do `A = new MyClass();` then it will created a new Object and that will be referenced by A.

As, there is no object referenced by A, there won't be any object type. However, we can know reference type here, which is MyClass.

Also, instanceof is a null safe operator. Meaning, null instanceof AnyClass will always return false.

Comment: How can we know the reference type which is MyClass at runtime?

Comment: Type is known at compile time itself. We don't need any runtime method/operator to get the type info. May I know what is the requirement here?

Comment: Added the requirement in the question @Darshan Mehta. Thanks!

Comment: In Java, you can't find the declared type of a null reference. All you can do is declare the type of null reference as Base type so that you can instantiate any sub class with it.

Comment: Agreed. But my requirement is to instantiate it with the declared type. Runtime. Which is the problem.